# No URLMap entries found in application configuration for a Node.JS application

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, gcloud, app.yaml

I am trying to deploy a node.js app to appEngine but he doesn't seem to like my app.yaml.

```
D:\projects\Personal\Project>gcloud app deploy
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: [D:\projects\Personal\Project\app.yaml]
No URLMap entries found in application configuration
  in "D:\projects\Personal\Project\app.yaml", line 10, column 12
```

Here's the app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: standard

skip_files:
 - ^node_modules$

env_variables:
  USER: 'dbUser'
  PASSWORD: 'DBPass'
  DB: 'URI to DB'
```

Am I missing something here? 
Could it be that it's because of my folder structure?

I have following structure:
- client
- server
---- server.js
- app.yaml

So the app.yaml is not in the server folder as otherwise it doesn't include the client folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standart environment with nodejs in AppEngine.

You must use `env: flex`.

see [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime).

Comment: Just to note, this is no longer the case: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/

Comment: Thats not true.. I can  deploy nodejs app in AppEngine with standard environment

Answer (score 7):

Now that **nodejs8** is supported in the standard environment (still in beta at this time), you must update your local gcloud environment to be able to deploy. Updating your gcloud components will make this warning go away.

**Run**

```
gcloud components update
```

**Update your app.yaml file**

See Google's github for the most basic example required: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/building-an-app/build/app.yaml

**Update your package.json**

Specify the appropriate compatible node version, example:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.0.0"
  },
```

**Full Tutorial**
On building a nodejs8 app in the App Engine standard environment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/building-app/

The standard environment deploys significantly faster than the flex environment.